# Is something in my code preventing <div class="rating"> from moving closer to the center of the screen horizontally?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

Actually, two questions:

(1) Is there something in my code that would prevent `<div class="rating">` from moving closer to the center? What can I add to actually move it closer to the center horizontally? (Side-note: CSS layout and positioning continue to be a mystery to me. I still don't understand when setting a margin or width will affect the position/layout and stop it from doing what I otherwise want it to do.)

(2) Why is `<div class="title">` not within the viewport when the window isn't maximized? What can I do to fix this?

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    
}

body {
  font-family: 'Spartan', sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.container {
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: url('./images/bg-pattern-top-desktop.svg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.content {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 77%;
}

.top {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.title {
    color: hsl(300, 43%, 22%);
    width: 25%;
    margin: auto;
}


.stars {
    display: inline;
    margin-right: 30px;
    }

.rating {
    color: hsl(300, 43%, 22%);
    font-weight: bold;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background-color: hsl(300, 24%, 96%);
    padding: 15px 50px 15px 25px;
    border-radius: .5em;
    margin: 10px;
}

.bottom {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.comment {
    background-color: hsl(300, 43%, 22%);
    border-radius: .5em;
    color: white;
    padding: 25px;
    margin: 15px;
}

.comment span {
    color: hsl(333, 80%, 67%);
}

.comment p {
    font-weight: lighter;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

.author img {
    border-radius: 50em;

}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="content">
        <div class="top">
          <div class="title">
            <h1>10,000+ of our users love our products.</h1>
            <p>
              We only provide great products combined with excellent customer service.
              See what our satisfied customers are saying about our services.
            </p>
          </div>
         
          <div class="spacer"></div>

          <div class="ratings">
            <div class="rating">
              <div class="stars">
                <img src="images/icon-star.svg" alt="star" />
                                <img src="images/icon-star.svg" alt="star" />
                                <img src="images/icon-star.svg" alt="star" />
                                <img src="images/icon-star.svg" alt="star" />
                                <img src="images/icon-star.svg" alt="star" />
              </div>
              <span>Rated 5 Stars in Reviews</span>
            </div>
            <div class="rating">
              <div class="stars">
                <img src="images/icon-star.svg" alt="star" />
                                <img src="images/icon-star.svg" alt="star" />
                                <img src="images/icon-star.svg" alt="star" />
                                <img src="images/icon-star.svg" alt="star" />
                                <img src="images/icon-star.svg" alt="star" />
              </div>
              <span>Rated 5 Stars in Report Guru</span>
            </div>
            <div class="rating">
              <div class="stars">
                <img src="images/icon-star.svg" alt="star" />
                                <img src="images/icon-star.svg" alt="star" />
                                <img src="images/icon-star.svg" alt="star" />
                                <img src="images/icon-star.svg" alt="star" />
                                <img src="images/icon-star.svg" alt="star" />
              </div>
              <span>Rated 5 Stars in BestTech</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="bottom">
          <div class="comment">
            <div class="author">
              <img src="images/image-colton.jpg" alt="colton" />
              <div class="profile">
                <div class="name">Colton Smith</div>
                <span>Verified Buyer</span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <p>
              "We needed the same printed design as the one we had ordered a week prior. Not only did they find the original order, but we also received it in time.
                            Excellent!"
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="comment">
            <div class="author">
              <img src="images/image-irene.jpg" alt="irene" />
              <div class="profile">
                <div class="name">Irene Roberts</div>
                <span>Verified Buyer</span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <p>
              "Customer service is always excellent and very quick turn around. Completely delighted with the simplicity of the purchase and the speed of delivery."
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="comment">
            <div class="author">
              <img src="images/image-anne.jpg" alt="anne" />
              <div class="profile">
                <div class="name">Anne Wallace</div>
                <span>Verified Buyer</span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <p>
              "Put an order with this company and can only praise them for the very high standard. Will definitely use them again and recommend them to everyone!"
            </p>
          </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>         
    </div>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `height: 100vh` to `min-height: 100vh`, this will give `.container` room to grow. At the moment, it's stuck to being `100vh` which pushes its content outside its boundaries.

Also, you need to add `justify-content: center` to `.top` and remove `margin: auto` from `.title` to move the ratings further left:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Spartan', sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.container {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-image: url('./images/bg-pattern-top-desktop.svg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 77%;
}

.top {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.title {
  color: hsl(300, 43%, 22%);
  width: 25%;
}

.stars {
  display: inline;
  margin-right: 30px;
}

.rating {
  color: hsl(300, 43%, 22%);
  font-weight: bold;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background-color: hsl(300, 24%, 96%);
  padding: 15px 50px 15px 25px;
  border-radius: .5em;
  margin: 10px;
}

.bottom {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.comment {
  background-color: hsl(300, 43%, 22%);
  border-radius: .5em;
  color: white;
  padding: 25px;
  margin: 15px;
}

.comment span {
  color: hsl(333, 80%, 67%);
}

.comment p {
  font-weight: lighter;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.author img {
  border-radius: 50em;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="top">
        <div class="title">
          <h1>10,000+ of our users love our products.</h1>
          <p>
            We only provide great products combined with excellent customer service. See what our satisfied customers are saying about our services.
          </p>
        </div>

        <div class="spacer"></div>

        <div class="ratings">
          <div class="rating">
            <div class="stars">
              <img src="images/icon-star.svg" alt="star" />
              <img src="images/icon-star.svg" alt="star" />
              <img src="images/icon-star.svg" alt="star" />
              <img src="images/icon-star.svg" alt="star" />
              <img src="images/icon-star.svg" alt="star" />
            </div>
            <span>Rated 5 Stars in Reviews</span>
          </div>
          <div class="rating">
            <div class="stars">
              <img src="images/icon-star.svg" alt="star" />
              <img src="images/icon-star.svg" alt="star" />
              <img src="images/icon-star.svg" alt="star" />
              <img src="images/icon-star.svg" alt="star" />
              <img src="images/icon-star.svg" alt="star" />
            </div>
            <span>Rated 5 Stars in Report Guru</span>
          </div>
          <div class="rating">
            <div class="stars">
              <img src="images/icon-star.svg" alt="star" />
              <img src="images/icon-star.svg" alt="star" />
              <img src="images/icon-star.svg" alt="star" />
              <img src="images/icon-star.svg" alt="star" />
              <img src="images/icon-star.svg" alt="star" />
            </div>
            <span>Rated 5 Stars in BestTech</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="bottom">
        <div class="comment">
          <div class="author">
            <img src="images/image-colton.jpg" alt="colton" />
            <div class="profile">
              <div class="name">Colton Smith</div>
              <span>Verified Buyer</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <p>
            "We needed the same printed design as the one we had ordered a week prior. Not only did they find the original order, but we also received it in time. Excellent!"
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="comment">
          <div class="author">
            <img src="images/image-irene.jpg" alt="irene" />
            <div class="profile">
              <div class="name">Irene Roberts</div>
              <span>Verified Buyer</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <p>
            "Customer service is always excellent and very quick turn around. Completely delighted with the simplicity of the purchase and the speed of delivery."
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="comment">
          <div class="author">
            <img src="images/image-anne.jpg" alt="anne" />
            <div class="profile">
              <div class="name">Anne Wallace</div>
              <span>Verified Buyer</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <p>
            "Put an order with this company and can only praise them for the very high standard. Will definitely use them again and recommend them to everyone!"
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</body>
```